# Sign in to AWS console without password

Tags: amazon-web-services

I received a username, access key ID and a secret access key from my organisation to access the Amazon Console. I'm a bit confused as to how I actually sign in using only this information.

The sign in page at [my-organisation.signin.aws.amazon.com/console](http://my-organisation.signin.aws.amazon.com/console) asks for a password, but I haven't received any password. What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to access AWS services as an end user:

1. Using CLI ([awscli](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/)) and API, for doing so you require access key ID and secret access key.
2. Using AWS web console for this you need a temporary password set by your AWS [IAM](http://aws.amazon.com/iam/) Administrator so that you could login and change it. Ask your Administrator to give you a temporary password if you think you require web console access as well.